# Scroll through 1d array and change specific values

Tags: c, arrays

My question is the following.
I want to scroll through a 1-D array, check only the values that are the 4th,5th,8th,9th aka:  0+4*n and 3+4*n.
Check if the value of this field is 0 and if yes make it 1 and STOP.
If it is not 0, go to the next value (0+4*n or 3+4*n) and make that 1 and STOP.
and so on..
What i have done so far is the following. The problem is that it **updates many values** at once..

```
        {
        for (i=0; i<nr; i++)
        {   for (n=0; n<((nr)/4); n++)
            if (i==(0+(n*4)))
            {
                if (array[i]==0)
                {
                    array[i]=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
            else if ((i==(3+(n*4))))
            {
                if (array[i]==0)
                {
                    array[i]=1;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        }
```

What am i doing wrong, and it doesn't stop but updates all values at once?

Comment: In the second for loop you're initializing "n" and making an increment for "i". Is it intentional?

Comment: It was too obvious but after hours in front of the pc i miissed it! Probably that was the fault! Thanks..

Comment: Not yet..I am updating the post above..Thanks for the help

Comment: It goes like this: the 4th, the 5th... Hallelujah! RIP Leonard.

Answer (score 0):

Your interpretation is incorrect: 4th, 5th, 8th, 9th etc. Correspond to `4*n` and `4*n+1`, not `4*n+3`

Here is the modified and simplified code:

```
    for (i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
        if (i % 4 <= 1) {
            if (array[i] == 0) {
                array[i] = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```